# How to only pull one column, but need both columns information

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a sql query, that works the way i want it, as i need it to pull the information, but i don't want my department column

Example

```
qry = """
select distinct 
    Department
    , (select count(*) from MyTable t2 where t2.Department = t1.Department and t2.CompletedTraining='Incomplete') as Total
from MyTable t1 ORDER BY Department ASC

df = pd.read_sql_query(qry, con)
print("Incomplete Training")
print(df)
```

Current Output:

```
Incomplete Training
   Department  Total
0       AQPSD      6
1         ASD      8
2          CO      2
3       ECARS      3
4          ED      6
5          EO      4
6         ISD      4
7         MLD      0
8        MSCD      5
9         OIS      0
10         RD      2
11        TTD      4
```

I would like my query to only put put Total column, but still have the same data, so output would be

```
   Incomplete 
     Training
0         6
1         8
2         2
3         3
4         6
5         4
6         4
7         0
8         5
9         0
10        2
11        4
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, you can remove a column by wrapping another query around it:

```sql
SELECT Total
FROM (SELECT ...original query... );
```

But in this case, if you replace DISTINCT with GROUP BY, you do not need the original column in the query output (and the subquery can be simplified by using the fact that in SQLite, a boolean expression results in `0` or `1`):

```sql
SELECT sum(CompletedTraining = 'Incomplete') AS Total
FROM MyTable AS t1
GROUP BY Department
ORDER BY Department ASC;
```